# Clojure on emacs fails when running cider-jack-in command

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

I had been using Clojure on emacs on my Bunsenlabs linux which was similar to Debian. Ones it stopped working. `cider-jack-in` command caused error. Could anybody help me to fix it?

The versions and error message are these:

`GNU Emacs 25.2.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.20) of 2017-09-12, modified by Debian`

`cider 20180207.239`

`clojure-mode 20180202.922`

`Leiningen 2.8.1 on Java 1.8.0_161 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM`

`Clojure 1.8.0`

```
Loading 00debian-vars...done Loading
/etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)... Loading
debian-ispell... Loading
/var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-default.el
(source)...done Loading debian-ispell...done Loading
/var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-dicts.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el
(source)...done For information about GNU Emacs and the GNU system,
type C-h C-a. completing-read-default: Command attempted to use
minibuffer while in minibuffer Quit Are you sure you want to run
`cider-jack-in' without a Clojure project? (y or n) y Making
nrepl-create-client-buffer-function local to *nrepl-server* while
let-bound! Making nrepl-use-this-as-repl-buffer local to
*nrepl-server* while let-bound! Starting nREPL server via /usr/bin/clojure -Sdeps '{:deps {org.clojure/tools.nrepl {:mvn/version
"0.2.13"} cider/orchard {:mvn/version "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"}
cider/cider-nrepl {:mvn/version "0.17.0-SNAPSHOT"}}}' -e '(require
(quote cider-nrepl.main)) (cider-nrepl.main/init
["cider.nrepl/cider-middleware"])'... error in process sentinel:
nrepl-server-sentinel: Could not start nREPL server: Exception in
thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: -Sdeps (No such file or
directory)  at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)     at
java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)  at
java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)    at
java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)     at
clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7365)  at
clojure.main$load_script.invokeStatic(main.clj:277)     at
clojure.main$script_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:337)  at
clojure.main$script_opt.invoke(main.clj:332)    at
clojure.main$main.invokeStatic(main.clj:423)    at
clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:386)    at
clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)    at
clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)  at
clojure.main.main(main.java:37)

error in process sentinel: Could not start nREPL server: Exception in
thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: -Sdeps (No such file or
directory)  at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)     at
java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)  at
java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)    at
java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)     at
clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7365)  at
clojure.main$load_script.invokeStatic(main.clj:277)     at
clojure.main$script_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:337)  at
clojure.main$script_opt.invoke(main.clj:332)    at
clojure.main$main.invokeStatic(main.clj:423)    at
clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:386)    at
clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)    at
clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)  at
clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
```

Comment: Could you please post your project.clj file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem disappeared when I created the project with `lein new app myappname` command. So the conclusion is that `cider-jack-in` doesn't work without a project.

Comment: Great to hear that, you should mark this as the correct answer so this won't show up in the "unanswered" questions list. Thanks :)

Comment: cider-0.16 version, you can run ```cider-jack-in``` without a project.clj