# clojure cider on catalina The lein executable isn’t on your ‘exec-path’

Tags: clojure, macos-catalina, leiningen, cider

I found these two links:

[Clojure on emacs fails...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48667078/clojure-on-emacs-fails-when-running-cider-jack-in-command) & [clojure isn't in your exec...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48992434/the-clojure-executable-isn-t-on-your-exec-path-even-though-lein-is-on-my-exe)

I'm unable to get cider to run on MacOS. I've been just using lein on the command line, but I would prefer to use cider.

I build a new project, like so:

```
lein new ec
```

open up core.clj

run `Mx cider-jack-in`

and I get:

The lein executable isn’t on your ‘exec-path’

I checked for the default in cider, and it is lein.

Is there any way to run cider on MacOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are some macOS related problems with exec path detection for emacs.

There is an emacs package, that should solve this issue: [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell).

It used to help me when i was using macos (like 3 years ago, but i think it is still valid)

Otherwise you can try to put an absolute path for `lein` (`which lein` in terminal) to `cider-lein-command`: `M-x customize-group [ret] cider [ret] -> Cider lein command`, that should also work.

Comment: I did the customize group option. That seems to work just fine. Thank you.